# Go a few levels up the DOM hierarchy to the containing table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML structure like so:

```
<tr class = "@rowOrdinal" id = "...">                            
    <td>
        <a href = "#">
            <img src = "/Content/updateIcon.gif" class = "updateResourceImageButton" id = "..." />
        </a>
        &nbsp;

        <a href = "#">
            <img src = "/Content/cancelIcon.gif" class = "cancelImageButton" />
        </a>
        &nbsp;
    </td>

    <td class = "hiddenColumn" id = ...>...</td>
    <td class = "resourceKeyColumn" id = ...>...</td>
    ... and so on...
```

When the update link is clicked, I'd like to get the reference to the row, i.e. `tr` element in which the update hyperlink was.

So, in the below event listener, I'd like to go up the DOM hierarchy a few levels. I could use simple JavaScript and use a `while` loop to get the `parentNode`, but how would I do that with jQuery?

```
function WireHandlers() {
    $('.updateResourceImageButton').click(UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler);
}

function UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler() {
  // how do I get a reference to the tr that contains
  // the hyperlink which is the source of this event?
}

$(document).ready(function () { WireHandlers(); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
function UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
}
```

Comment: F*king wow! jQuery is fa king brilliant! That is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thanks very much. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function WireHandlers() {
    $('.updateResourceImageButton').click( function(){

        var trParent = $( this ).parent().parent();
        UpdateResourceLinkClickedHandler();
    });
}
```

Not sure why you need parent tr reference, so haven't used it in my example

Comment: you can also do var trParent = $( this ).parent( "tr" );

Comment: Thank you very much, gurvinder. That is so simple. I love jQuery. :-)